# How do I wait for FileReader onload to complete first

Tags: javascript, angular, web, filereader, onload

I am working with FileReader and I have come across an issue with the onLoad method of FileReader not being executed synchronously with the rest of the code. Basically I have 2 functions like these:

```
    imageExists(url, callback) {
      var img = new Image();
      img.onload = function () { callback(true); };
      img.onerror = function () { callback(false); };
      img.src = url;
    }

    isImageCorrupt(file): boolean {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      var isCorrupt = false;
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      reader.onload = (e) => {
        this.imageExists(e.target.result, (exists) => {
            if (exists) {
                isCorrupt = false;
                // Image is not corrupt
            } else {
                isCorrupt = true;
                //Image is corrupt
            }
        });
    };

    return isCorrupt;
   }
```

The isImageCorrupt() function calls the reader.onLoad which calls the imageExists callback function, which also contains a image onload method.

The problem is that during the execution of the isImageCorrupt() function, the reader.onLoad has not changed the value of isCorrupt yet but the function has returned the value in the last line which is always false.

I want my function to wait for the reader.onLoad to finish its execution before the function returns the value.

Answer (score 2):

You could use Promises.    The code could be still refactorized using async/await

```
    isImageCorrupt(file): Promise<boolean> {
      return new Promise<boolean>((resolve,reject)=>{
      var reader = new FileReader();
      
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      reader.onload = ()=>{
      var img = new Image();
      img.src = reader.result;
            img.onload = function () {
              resolve(false);
            };
            img.onerror = function () {
              resolve(true);
            };
            
}

reader.onerror=()=>{reject(true)}
        });
    };


   
       isImageCorrupt(yourFile).then((result)=>{/*HERE USE RESULT*/},(error)=>{HERE USE ERROR RESULT})
```

However you shouldn't return true o false, but resolve if it's ok and reject otherwise, whithout a boolean value in this way

```
isImageCorrupt(file): Promise<void> {
          return new Promise<void>((resolve,reject)=>{
          var reader = new FileReader();
          
          reader.readAsDataURL(file);
          reader.onload = ()=>{
          var img = new Image();
          img.src = reader.result;
                img.onload = function () {
                  resolve();
                };
                img.onerror = function () {
                  reject();
                };
                
    }
    
    reader.onerror=()=>{reject()}
            });
        };
    
    
       
       

     isImageCorrupt(yourFile).then(()=>{/*HERE OK*/},()=> {HERE 
  THERE WAS SOME ERROR/PROBLEM})
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe something like this?

```
 isImageCorrupt(file): Promise<Boolean> {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = (e) => {
            var img = new Image();
            img.onload = function () {
              resolve(false);
            };
            img.onerror = function () {
              resolve(true);
            };
            img.src = <string>e.target.result;
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    });
}
```

*disclaimer: I did not test it

Comment: It doesnt seem to be working. Maybe the way I am calling it is wrong?
This is the way I am calling the function:
      if (this.isImageCorrupt(file)) { }

Comment: Yes, it's wrong. You can't use result of asynchronous code in synchronous code.  You have to use `then()` function like in my answer.   Another approach could be to use `FileReaderSync` that read a file in a synchronous way, but can be used only in a worker